# Package install in Octave erros - Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: octave

ok this seems like a really silly question but for some reason I'm having issues installing a package into octave (using Ubuntu 12.04). I used the command:

```
pkg install signal-1.3.0.tar.gz
```

and got the error:

```
warning: file signal-1.3.0.tar.gz does not exist
```

But the file does exist and I have the tar file in the same folder as octave. I can't work out what the issue is... any ideas?? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: if you're on Ubuntu, why are you not using `apt-get install octave-signal` ?

Comment: That's not working for me, I'm getting this error: `The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 octave : Breaks: octave-signal (<= 1.2.2-1) but 1.0.11-2 is to be installed
 octave-signal : Depends: octave-optim (>= 1.0.5) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: octave-control but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: octave-specfun but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: octave3.2 (>= 3.2.0-1) but it is not going to be installed
`